# Security implications of exposed Dropbox API key and secret

Tags: appsec

I've noticed that the Dropbox PHP SDK requires you to put your API credentials in a JSON file that might be publicly available if the SDK code is placed within the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory. What are the security implications if an attacker discovers these?

Comment: Why not check out the API and see for yourself what you would be able to do with the credentials?

Comment: Just did. Apparently it would be possible to steal files from the authenticated user's dropbox but the limitation is that the oauth server checks the redirect URI so I'm unable to get an access token. Still bad though.

Comment: That could be bypassed via DNS spoofing. Which is possible in targeted attacks.

Comment: Can you give me a scenario for that? Other than being on the same physical network with the victim.

Comment: It would have to involve some way via man in the middle. The app secret is also used to verify to the application itself that it's really talking with Dropbox's servers. If you were to MitM the application server you could pose as Dropbox, grabbing tokens and whatnot.

Comment: Yes, indeed, although if there's a possibility to do MITM between the app and the servers or to perform the DNS poisoning there are bigger problems than just public API secrets. Thanks anyway

Comment: The appears in this case, that the API secret is simply just a security mitigation. Like two-factor authentication.

Comment: Not really. It's used to authenticate the server: https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/developers/oauth2-diagram.png

Comment: That's oversimplified. Much of the authentication actually happens between the client and Dropbox directly. But after that the server can communicate to Dropbox without the client and, and in such cases the secret is used to protect the communications. The secret itself ins't actually required for proper authentication on the client side. It's really only used for server-to-server connections.

Answer (score 1):

> ... the Dropbox PHP SDK requires you to put your API credentials in a
>   JSON file that might be publicly available if the SDK code is placed
>   within the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.

This is definitely not true. I think some of the example apps use a nearby JSON file to store various credentials for convenience, but there's nothing in the SDK that requires you to do that. (You could store the JSON file elsewhere, and the constructor for `AppInfo` takes a key and secret, so you can manage them however you want.)

For most apps it's probably not a big deal to expose the app secret, but I would still discourage developers from doing so.

To learn more, look around for discussions about exposing OAuth consumer secrets. Notably, mobile apps typically **do** expose those secrets (at least in OAuth 1), so there's been a fair amount of discussion of the security implications.

Comment: OK, maybe it doesn't require you to store your credentials in a JSON file but they are encouraging developers to do so: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/php

Comment: I looked online for some discussions and the very first one I found raised the same concerns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1934234/539153 and pointed out that they decided to proxy all the information through their server.

Comment: On the web I wasn't able to create a proof of concept because the Dropbox oauth checks the redirect URL but if I think about it, having your secrets exposed mean that any other app on your mobile phone would be able to use those to connect to dropbox/facebook and other services that use oauth and just steal users' info without the knowledge of the user.

Comment: Knowing an app's secret doesn't let you access any user's information.

Comment: If the user previously authorized the app - it will silently skip the "Allow this app to access your info" and will give you an access token right away.

Comment: But you would need to somehow control the target of the redirect (which is specified in advance by the app owner).

Comment: I was not aware that there's a redirect to an URL (myapp://) in the mobile flow as well. Now it seems indeed that although you have the secrets it's hard to get an access token. Thank you